# Diffrence in result from postgresql(PostGIS) and SQL (Sptial)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008

I have two points and I have to calculate difference between them.

I using below query in SQL.

```
SELECT geography::Point(27.185425, 88.124582, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(27.1854258, 88.124500, 4326));
```

Its running fine and result is :

```
8.12599260290125
```

Now with same point when I am running below query in postgresql.

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(27.185425 88.124582)',4326),ST_GeomFromText('POINT(27.1854258 88.124500)', 4326));
```

and Now result is :

```
8.20039023523232
```

Can anyone tell me why there is difference in results when calculating distance between two points?

Comment: Could one be using a spherical geometry? http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html vs http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html or even http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html ?

Comment: I have checked all your link but no help for me. I am storing the latitude and longitude values of data type GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)

Comment: I could not find any specifics about the internal workings of this calculation, I suspect that the difference is in underlying data types/calculation logic, specifically rounding. I sugest you find and independent way to very the result. Note: I did enounter calculation differences with NUMERIC data types before between Sybase and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things that have caught you out here.

In the SQL Server version using the Point, the order of the coordinate is Lat Lon, eg Y X. The OGC Point construct is X Y or Lon Lat.

The last issue is that the PostGIS query is treating the objects as Geometries and doing a cartesian distance on them. You need to explicitly make them Geographies.

Here's a few ways to do the PostGIS query. I've swapped the coordinate order

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(88.124582 27.185425)',4326)::geography,
               ST_GeomFromText('POINT(88.124500 27.1854258)',4326)::geography);

SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124582 27.185425)'),
               ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124500 27.1854258)'));


SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist 
FROM (SELECT
ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124582 27.185425)') As gg1,
ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(88.124500 27.1854258)') As gg2
) As foo  ;
```